# How do I copy text from a dialog box?

Tags: windows, screen-scraping

In Windows sometimes I get an error dialog with long text. Manually typing out the exact details of an error message can be an annoying and lengthy process.

Is there way to copy text from a Windows dialog box?

Comment: Sometimes **`Ctrl + Insert`** will also do the trick - [How to copy the text of an error message into a text editor](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-copy-the-text-of-an-error-message-into-a-text-editor-f0affc02-fcd5-df53-4051-d0ca4b8afaf4)

Comment: Windows [PowerToys Text Extractor Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/text-extractor) may also prove useful.

Answer (score 23):

Try just hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while the dialog has focus.  If it is a normal modal Windows message box, it will put the text in the dialog in the clipboard for you.

The copied text should look something like this:

```
---------------------------
Window Title
---------------------------
The dialog box main text
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Comment: "If" is the important word here! Windows 7 is better than Vista is better than XP for this it seems.

Comment: Worked great in Windows 10 here!

Answer (score 7):

If you have OneNote, you can take a screen clip, then right-click the pasted image (in OneNote) and select "Copy Text from Picture".

I usually have success with it. Sometimes I need to do a little editing though.

Answer (score 6):

A bit of an old question, but here is a different solution:

For windows that don't natively support Ctrl+C, there are several utilities which will poke around all current processes and let you pull the text from *standard* window objects (listboxes, comboboxes, etc.)

I used one years ago that worked well, but can't remember the name of it.  Here's another I just found by doing a quick search:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Textify](http://rammichael.com/textify), which can grab text with a mouse click.

> Have you ever wanted to copy some text from a dialog box which doesn’t provide such functionality?
>
> Textify was created to solve this problem: you can point your mouse over the text, click on the mouse shortcut (Shift + Middle click by default), and get a selectable view of the text.

[image: demo video]

Answer (score 2):

For dialogs and controls that don’t have a copy ability built-in, I prefer to use [WinSpy++](http://catch22.net/software/winspy) to capture the raw text. (You simply use the picker-tool to select the window/control in question and then copy the text from the caption field.)

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-copy-text-or-error-messages-from-any-dialog-boxes-in-windows/) lists 7 programs for that (in case Ctrl+C doesn't work). [ShoWin 2.0](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/showin.aspx) is by McAfee and works fine though i wish its preview was a little bigger.

Answer (score 0):

This came up in my search for “copy windows title” and though OP is specifically requesting the contents of a dialog; if you wanted to copy more “locked” text from a window there is ‘Microsoft Spy ++’.  It’s what most of those are emulating as it’s been around A LONG time, before it had the Microsoft tag.  It’s also more current than most of those suggest and will have longer support.  It’s always been installed with Visual Studio (non-express) since at least 6.0; so if you have VS, search ‘spy’.  It allows you to look at a lot of things like controls and text from windows.  You can download the current and previous version here: http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/11/microsoft-spy-or-spyxx-for-download.html  Basic start, click the goggles and then drag the target to the window you want info from, click ok and then you can go through things.  For more information search on how to use.

Tip:  Window Caption text box isn’t so friendly, either from start or pressing home to get to start, hold shift and hit end then Ctrl+C to copy entire title.  (Ctrl+A nor triple click work)