# How to copy text from webpage dialog?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, html, website, webpage

I am using a browser based (mainly internet explorer) application, sometimes I need to click on input boxes to get the possible list of options. Is there a way to copy the popped up ([like this](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unitek.com%2Ftraining%2Fmicrosoft%2Fcrm%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2008%2F01%2Fsystem-settings-webpage-dialog.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unitek.com%2Ftraining%2Fmicrosoft%2Fcrm%2Fblog%2Fcategory%2Fmicrosoft-crm-30%2F&h=454&w=504&tbnid=70_8uzrADKIklM%3A&zoom=1&docid=pXXZSBl5BiBiZM&ei=B_CrU-nsOdO7uASK9IHYBA&tbm=isch&ved=0CFMQMygsMCw&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=520&page=2&start=24&ndsp=24)) options' inner HTML? I am not asking the code approach but something like view source which a normal user can also view, something like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/130205/tool-to-copy-text-from-dialog-windows)!

Note - the popped webpage dialog does not allows right click -> view source (it's disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the answers in the link you provided, `Ctrl + C` should work.

Just click on the popup and Press `Ctrl + C`, the text would be copied into your clipboard.

Comment: no it's not working, i already tried that

Comment: Can you share the link of the web application and what exactly are you trying to do with that?

Comment: https://login.advancedmd.com/

Comment: You want to capture what? The username is blank and this kind of things on this website?

Comment: the web dialog is something like [this](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unitek.com%2Ftraining%2Fmicrosoft%2Fcrm%2Fblog%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2008%2F01%2Fsystem-settings-webpage-dialog.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unitek.com%2Ftraining%2Fmicrosoft%2Fcrm%2Fblog%2Fcategory%2Fmicrosoft-crm-30%2F&h=454&w=504&tbnid=70_8uzrADKIklM%3A&zoom=1&docid=pXXZSBl5BiBiZM&ei=B_CrU-nsOdO7uASK9IHYBA&tbm=isch&ved=0CFMQMygsMCw&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=520&page=2&start=24&ndsp=24)

Comment: and you want to capture exactly what in this?